# Bootstrap CSS Button Issue, not changing colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap button that looks like this:

[image]

The HTML code fr this button is this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary.custom-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
   More Info
</button>
```

For Some reason my CSS is not showing up. I thought it was because I had other buttons on my page and their CSS was conflicting, so I changed the class to separate them:

```
<button class="btn-filter active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
```

It was just `bt`n and I changed it to `btn-filter` so I could easily tell the difference in my CSS, but I am still having trouble with the custom btn not changing to the correct color.

Here is m y CSS:

```
  <style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }

  /* Center website */
  .main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }

  .row {
    margin: 10px -16px;
  }

  /* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
  .row,
  .row > .column {
    padding: 8px;
  }

  /* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
  }

  /* Clear floats after rows */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  /* Content */
  .content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  /* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
  .show {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Style the buttons */
  .btn-filter {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .btn-filter:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .btn-filter.active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
  }


    .slidecontainer {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: #E7E7E7;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    .slider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      background: #4CAF50;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      background: #4CAF50;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    body {
      padding-top: 75px;
    }


    .footer {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: max-content;
      display: inline-block !important;

    }

    .wrapper {
      display: block;
    }

    #sidebar {
      min-width: 250px;
      max-width: 250px;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: -250px;
      z-index: 99999;
      background: #212529;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      padding: 1em;
    }

    #sidebar.active {
      left: 0;
    }

    .overlay {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      z-index: 9999;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* display .overlay when it has the .active class */
    .overlay.active {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    #dismiss {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      position: absolute;
      /* top right corner of the sidebar */
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      color: #dc880a;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
      padding: 20px;
      background: #212529;
    }

    #sidebar ul.components {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }

    #sidebar ul p {
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      display: block;
      color: #dc880a;
    }


    #sidebar ul li.active>a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
      color: #fff;
      background: #6d7fcc;
    }

    ul ul a {
      font-size: 0.9em !important;
      padding-left: 30px !important;
      background: #6d7fcc;
    }

    .btn-primary.custom-btn {
        background-color: #dc880a;
        border-color: #dc880a;

    }

    * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
      }
  </style>
```

I am not sure what I am missing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the css classes on your button. Specifically, `class="btn-primary.custom-btn"` needs to change to `class="btn-primary custom-btn"`.

The reason is that the CSS selector `.btn-primary.custom-btn` means "all elements with both btn-primary and custom-btn classes" but the class actually applied to the button is a single class called `btn-primary.custom-btn`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary custom-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
   More Info
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't pick up your style is because you have incorrect class name. You need to change the button class name from `class="btn-primary.custom-btn"` to `class="btn-primary custom-btn"`. You don't need the dot when giving HTML element a class name.